# Can you mass kick people from a server using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I want to have a moderation bot that kicks all members with a certain role e.g. "gamer" from the server. is this possible. I have a normal kick/ ban command and despite searching the web for ages I cant find any answers. Amy help would be hugely appreciated.
Thanks.

```py
@client.command(aliases=['k'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx,member : discord.Member, *,reason="No reason provided"):
    await member.send(f"You have been kicked from GamerTown by Oli, Becasue: {reason}")
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. You can iterate through members in the guild and check if they have the specific role.

```py
@client.command()
async def role_kick(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    [await member.kick() for member in ctx.guild.members if role in member.roles]
```

So when you type `prefix+role_kick @gamer`,it will kick all the users with the role `gamer`.